# Password protecting folder or directory in java or python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I am working on a project in which I need to implement a functionality wherein a folder or directory is protected using a password. As in, when someone tries to open that particular folder, a password prompt is presented to them. If correct password is entered, then folder access is granted or else not.
Is this possible using python or Java ? Is yes then how ? And if not then which language can be used ?
I tried searching a lot but nothing helpful came out of it.

Comment: why tag c# when you're demanding python or java?

Comment: If your user can read it :) with some effort one can bypass password, create a zip protected file or better encrypt it

Answer (score -1):

If you mean folders on the file system then you could mimick this behavior by storing files in a password protected zip file.

If you mean conceptual folders within your application then you are free to implement authentication any way you want. Normally this involves a user logging in to your application to gain access to the protected resources.

Comment: My entire project is in a folder and it has certain html and js files as well. I dont want the user meddling with them. However the codebase should have access to them. If I use a zip, will it help me achieve the above mentioned functionality ?

Comment: Usually if you distribute your project in archived form (e.g. a java .war file) users won't 'meddle' with any content. However, if the code is running on a machine under their control you can never prevent them to do so if they really want to. Even if you password protect the folder, the application would still need to gain access. A smart user could reverse engineer the process and also gain access.

Comment: I shall try zipping the files and then give the project a run. Hopefully it should get access to the zipped js files. Will get back to you with the result in some time.